# jQuery DataTables Column Hiding

Tags: jquery, datatables, responsive

I want to have a DataTable that displays a few columns, then shows data for other unseen columns underneath (by clicking a plus sign at the start of the row). However, I have only been able to see the "+" sign when the window width is small enough to force columns already shown in the table to be moved off.

There is a fiddle that contains a sample of the problem I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/ebRXw/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );
   } );
```

I hoped that making the table responsive would do the trick, with no luck.

The 3rd column is being "hidden", but there is no "+" sign until you decrease the width where the table is enough to require shifting columns off the table. I am stuck on how to manually force certain columns to be hidden while always showing the "+" sign, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `class="none"` to the `th` seems to do what you need:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th class="none">Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th class="none">Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I've also added the `display responsive nowrap` classes to the table:

```
<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yk06fbxa/) based on your data, I've removed the CSS...

Comment: Thank you! I was sure I was missing something simple..still relatively new to this

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck on how to manually force certain columns to be hidden while always showing the "+" sign, and any help would be appreciated.

So to force the plugin to show the plus icon by default you can add the class `collapsed` to your table after you apply the dataTables plugin.

```
 $('#example').addClass('collapsed');
```

here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/2387/)**